# What is a language for sound control

Tags: java, python, matlab, audio

I'm trying to make a program that roughly does the following:

```
produceBeepSound(double loudness);
```

can I do such a thing in Java? I need it to be very precise. What about matlab? Which language would be best for this task. The language must have a GUI component.

Comment: you can do this with any of the languages you listed. Python would likely be the easiest: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307305/play-a-sound-with-python

Comment: See [Beeper](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8632160/418556).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Java Media Framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html) to produce sound but it is not necessary because you can work with [javax.sound.sampled](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/package-summary.html) package and integrate it with [Java Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

In python take a look at [pyaudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) library and also take a look at [PythonInMusic](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic) it has a whole lot of collection of various A/V module.

Also, take a look at [Beeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632104/sine-wave-sound-generator-in-java/8632160#8632160).

> It is a  GUI program, using only J2SE classes, that can produce a sound
>   of configurable tone & duration, and (with a bit of tweaking) at
>   different raw volumes

Thanks to @Andrew for once again correcting me.

Comment: The JMF has not been necessary for making sound in Java since 1.3 and the introduction of the `javax.sound.sampled` package.  Please get with the times.  ;)  My 1st comment links to code with a GUI, using *only J2SE classes,* that can produce a sound of configurable tone & duration, and (with a bit of tweaking) at different raw volumes.

Comment: Great edit, but it could be better to qualify the 'is not in use' to 'has not been *necessary* to work with *sampled sound*'.  The reason for the clarification is that I used JMF within the last few months (in a 1.6 JRE) to make MOV files from JPEGs (and I don't want to feel like a dinosaur for using an abandoned API).

Comment: @AndrewThompson: thanks once again. Lot to learn..lot to learn :).

Comment: Yep.  The answer is now to a point where I just got to +1.  :)

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB, just use the SOUND function:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sound.html

You can specify a vector which represents your signal, and the amplitude on that vector will determine loudness, so its a matter of simple scaling.

Comment: In fact, you can even control the sample rate and bit depth using that function.

Comment: every time I try the "sound" function it tells me I have too many arguments. it doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: Unless the function is "lying"... :),.. could you post the code which shows how you are calling SOUND?

Answer (score 0):

you can try [Csound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Csound). There is API for java.

You should also check this wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_audio_synthesis_environments.

But if you need somthing simple you can try:

```
java.awt.Toolkit.beep();
```

or

```
System.out.println((char)7);
```

But you won't have volume control.

Probably my favourite approach would be HTML 5 audio api - https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API#Writing_Audio

Answer (score 0):

on windows actually any language can emit a sound just outputting ascii character "\007". [Here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0001.html) is a nice article about how to do it in java.