# Sound in processing without using external libraries

Tags: processing

I'm currently working on a project in Processing(version 3.1.1) for school which doesn't allow the use of external libraries(the project, that is)

I've successfully used the minim library and the Sound library before I found out external libraries aren't allowed. I can't find any information about adding sound to processing without the use of either of those. If anyone can help me further, link me to information or inform me it's not possible to do without external libraries, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I hope the [Processing 3 Sound library](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/sound/index.html) by Processing Foundation isn't considered an external library by your school.

Otherwise you'll have to use raw Java using the [javax.sound](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/index.html) package.
You can find a couple of handy answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632104/sine-wave-sound-generator-in-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064066/does-java-have-built-in-libraries-for-audio-synthesis/2065693#2065693)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **no**, there isn't a way to play sound using vanilla Processing.

The whole point of the Minim library is to add this functionality to Processing.

Keep in mind that Processing is written using Java, so you can use Java code inside your Processing sketch. Depending on how you're defining "external library", you could use Java to play a sound file. Google "Java play sound file" for a ton of results.

However, that really seems like overkill. Just use Minim. If you can't use Minim, then don't worry about adding sound.