# SourceDataLine.drain() hangs on OSX

Tags: java, macos, javasound

My game plays back sound via the usual method:

```
sdl.open();
sdl.start();
sdl.write(data, 0, data.length);
sdl.drain();
sdl.stop();
sdl.close();
```

And the user may cancel the playback (asynchronously):

```
sdl.stop();
```

This cancellation works nicely under Windows, but for one user running OSX 10.5.8 with Java 6 the program hangs. Threaddump shows the playback thread is inside drain(): `com.sun.media.sound.MixerSourceLine.nDrain`. If the user doesn't interrupt the sound, it completes nicely and the application continues.

My questions are:

- Is this an OSX Java bug?
- Should I use `sdl.close()` instead of stop?
- Any suggestions or experience on a workaround?

**Edit**: I found [this](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4392953) bug report with similar effects, but the page says it is fixed.

Comment: This [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064066/does-java-have-built-in-libraries-for-audio-synthesis/2065693#2065693) completes normally on Mac OSX 10.5.8, Java 6.

Comment: @trashgod That example does not get closed asynchronously. I mentioned in the question that when not interrupted, the sound plays fine.

Comment: Do you get the same behavior using [BigClip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667454/playing-audio-file-in-java-application/5668510#5668510)?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I can't really experiment, because the issue came through an error report from an OSX user without any programming experience (and I'm developing on a Windows machine). It took a hour to explain how to get the threaddump done on his system. Looking at your code it uses smaller blocks for the audio and it may get stopped before the drain() gets called. My code puts the entire audio into the sound buffer and ends up calling drain() fairly quickly after then.

Comment: @Andrew: I've elaborated below, but I welcome your critical insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, this example using `close()` exits normally under either Java 5 or 6.

Invoking `stop()`, rather than `close()`, on the EDT hangs both Java 5 and 6 unless the `line` has already been closed normally on the initial thread. This appears to be the expected result of [`drain()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html#drain%28%29) blocking, as a stopped line can't drain.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803310
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065693
 */
public class Tone {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LineUnavailableException {
        final AudioFormat af =
            new AudioFormat(Note.SAMPLE_RATE, 8, 1, true, true);
        final SourceDataLine line = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(af);
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Halt");
                //line.stop(); // stops and hangs on drain
                line.close();
            }
        });
        line.open(af, Note.SAMPLE_RATE);
        line.start();
        for (Note n : Note.values()) {
            play(line, n, 500);
            play(line, Note.REST, 10);
        }
        line.drain();
        line.close();
    }

    private static void play(SourceDataLine line, Note note, int ms) {
        ms = Math.min(ms, Note.SECONDS * 1000);
        int length = Note.SAMPLE_RATE * ms / 1000;
        int count = line.write(note.data(), 0, length);
    }
}
```

Requires [`Note`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064066/does-java-have-built-in-libraries-for-audio-synthesis/2065693#2065693).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It seems the Windows JRE does not conform the spec. I'll ask the user to try the game with these modifications.