# How to play a sound when a key is pressed

Tags: java, swing

I would like to make a program that allows the user to type in a message. The message will be typed in a JTextField. I would like to make it so that when every key is pressed it will play a short sound. I have the sound file as an mp3, its a short beep.

I only want it to work for keys A - Z, 0 - 9, backspace, and space.

I know how I would do this with the enter key; an action listener. I don't know how to do this with every key that is pressed before hitting enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`KeyListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) in a `JTextField` will likely have problems with focus.

Instead, you can [bind a key](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to an [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) that plays a short [`Tone`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2065693/230513).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a KeyListener to your text field.

Here is some [example documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html).

[Here is a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045384/playing-mp3-and-wav-in-java) from this site that will help in playing the mp3.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The best bet I would say is use a KeyListener. Implement that within your class, create the instance of whatever sound class you're going to use, create a method and within the keyPressed method, call your function, here is an example of how to do that. http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/108969/linking-jbuttons-to-key-events-through-key-listeners