# Impossible to play several sounds when I pressed several Jbuttons

Tags: java, swing, audio, jbutton, javasound

I have three buttons in my java program that can play three different sounds. Look at my code:

```
    import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;

public class VueEditeurEmail extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel container = new JPanel();
    private JPanel containerHaut = new JPanel();
    private JPanel containerAction = new JPanel();
    private JButton boutonEnvoyer = new JButton("Envoi");
    private JButton boutonAnnuler = new JButton("Annuler");
    private JButton contacts = new JButton("Contacts");
    private JButton coller = new JButton("Coller");
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    private ChampsTexte champs1 = new ChampsTexte("Expéditeur :", "");
    private ChampsTexte champs2 = new ChampsTexte("Destinataire :", "");
    private ChampsTexte champs3 = new ChampsTexte("Objet :", "");
    private JOptionPane jop1 = new JOptionPane();
    private JOptionPane jop2 = new JOptionPane();
    private JOptionPane jop3 = new JOptionPane();
    final Clipboard clipboard = container.getToolkit().getSystemClipboard();


    public VueEditeurEmail() {
        this.setTitle("Expéditeur de Message");
        this.setSize(500, 300);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        containerHaut.setLayout(new BoxLayout(containerHaut, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        containerHaut.add(champs1);
        containerHaut.add(champs2);
        containerHaut.add(contacts);
        containerHaut.add(coller);
        containerHaut.add(champs3);

        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        JScrollPane scrollPan = new JScrollPane(textArea);

        container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        container.setBackground(Color.white);
        container.add(containerHaut, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        container.add(scrollPan, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        container.add(containerAction, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        containerAction.add(boutonEnvoyer, BorderLayout.EAST);
        containerAction.add(boutonAnnuler, BorderLayout.WEST);

        contacts.addActionListener(this);
        boutonEnvoyer.addActionListener(this);
        boutonAnnuler.addActionListener(this);
        coller.addActionListener(this);

        this.setContentPane(container);
        this.setVisible(true);

        containerHaut.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        champs1.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        champs2.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        champs3.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        textArea.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        boutonEnvoyer.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        boutonAnnuler.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

    }

        public void playSound(String soundName){
            try{
                AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(soundName).getAbsoluteFile( ));
                Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip( );
                clip.open(audioInputStream);
                clip.start( );
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println("Erreur lors de la lecture du son");
                ex.printStackTrace( );
            }
        }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent E) {

        if(E.getSource() == boutonEnvoyer){
            playSound("Envoyé.wav");
            Email monEmail = new Email(champs1.getTexte(), champs2.getTexte(), champs3.getTexte(), textArea.getText());
            monEmail.EnvoiSMTP("admpcsrv1.uha.fr", 25);


            ImageIcon img1 = new ImageIcon("Images/succès.png");
            jop1.showMessageDialog(null, "L'Email a bien été envoyé", "Envoi réussi", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, img1);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        else if(E.getSource() == boutonAnnuler){
            playSound("Annulé.wav");
            ImageIcon img2 = new ImageIcon("Images/annuler.png");
            jop2.showMessageDialog(null, "Appuyer sur OK pour confirmer l'annulation", "Annulation", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, img2);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        else if (E.getSource() == contacts){
            playSound("OuvertureContacts.wav");
            ImageIcon img3 = new ImageIcon("Images/OuvertureContacts.png");
            jop3.showMessageDialog(null, "Ouverture de la liste des contacts, appuyer sur Ok pour fermer ce popup", "Liste des contacts", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, img3);
            File file = new File("Fichiers/InfosContacts.xls");
            try{
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
            }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Ouverture du fichier impossible");
            }

        }

        else if (E.getSource() == coller){
            Transferable clipData = clipboard.getContents(clipboard);
            try{
                if(clipData.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)){
                String s = (String)(clipData.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor));
                champs2.fieldTexte.replaceSelection(s);
                }
            }catch(Exception ufe){}
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        VueEditeurEmail monEditeur = new VueEditeurEmail();

    }
}
```

When I press the "contacts" button, the sound "OuvertureContacts.wav" is well played. But after, when I press the "boutonEnvoyer" button or the "boutonAnnuler" button, their sounds are not played ... What is the problem , I use the same code for the three buttons but when I press one button, the other doesn't play sounds after the first press !

I really appreciate your help, thanks in advance !

Comment: Just from a glance, have you tried closing the audioInputStream after its use?

Comment: Maybe the é characters are not read the right way. Did you try to replace them by standerd e ?

Comment: Audio should also be played in its own thread

Comment: You should play your songs in another thread cause if you play in the same thread as the gui `EDT` it's gonna block

Comment: I was always under the impression that stuff that was retrieved from the AudioSystem for playing ran in its own thread, silly me.

Comment: @MadProgrammer and you are both right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your fragment raises several issues:

- Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
- Give each distinct sound its own stream and clip; initialize each clip just once, rather than every time the clip is played.

  ```
  AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(…);
  Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip( );
  clip.open(audioInputStream);
  ```
- Although the audio system plays the clip in a separate thread, you may want to position and  `start()` the clip in a separate thread; this will minimize latency on the EDT and enhance *liveness*.

  ```
  private void playSound() {
      Runnable soundPlayer = new Runnable() {

          @Override
          public void run() {
              try {
                  clip.setMicrosecondPosition(0);
                  clip.start();
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
      };
      new Thread(soundPlayer).start();
  }
  ```
- See also the [javasound](/questions/tagged/javasound) tag [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) and this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2065693/230513).

Addendum: SSCCE

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17130160/230513
 * @see http://pscode.org/media/
 * @see http://www.soundjay.com/beep-sounds-1.html
 */
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().display();
            }
        });
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f.add(new JButton(new SoundAction("Play 1",
            "http://pscode.org/media/leftright.wav")));
        f.add(new JButton(new SoundAction("Play 2",
            "http://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-1.wav")));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    class SoundAction extends AbstractAction {

        private Clip clip;

        public SoundAction(String name, String location) {
            super(name);
            try {
                URL url = new URL(location);
                AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
                clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(ais);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Runnable optional
            Runnable soundPlayer = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        clip.setMicrosecondPosition(0);
                        clip.start();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                    }
                }
            };
            new Thread(soundPlayer).start();
        }
    }
}
```