# How can i add button sound for a swing calculator project

Tags: java, swing

I am building a simple calculator project in Java using *Swing* and I want to play a sound when the user clicks on the buttons in the app. I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The Oracle tutorial [Sound](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/index.html) might help you.  Adding sound to a Swing application is not a simple process.  You don't want to block the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) playing sound.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64509691/how-can-i-add-some-sound-to-my-java-jframe/64509714#64509714 for a simple example.

Comment: This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17767350/230513) illustrates using `javax.sound.midi`. If this is not a duplicate, please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows your revised approach.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is implement an `OnTouchListener`

on the button and use the `AudioManager.playSoundEffect()` public method. Code is shown below:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
float vol = 0.5; //This will be half of the default system sound
am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEY_CLICK, vol);
```

Comment: As far as I am aware, [Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) is for desktop applications while `OnTouchListener` is part of Android API and does not exist in Java SE.