# Java - Generating Tones with different amplitudes makes different tones

Tags: java, audio, synthesizer

I am creating tones in my Java-program.
So there is a number of oscillator modules which produce the samples I need so that I can play more than one tone at a time. These samples are added and played. 
If I select a low amplitude, e.g. 100, everything works fine (normalized it in Audacity):

[image: Sinus]

But if I select a higher amplitude, in this case Short.MAX_VALUE, the created tone looks and sounds strange:

[image: Sinus2]

The samples are created here (source: http://www.wolinlabs.com/blog/java.sine.wave.html):

```
    short value;
    if (type == TYPE_SINE)
    {
        cycleIncrease = frequency / parent.getSamplingRate();
        value = (short) (amplitude * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * cyclePosition));
        cyclePosition += cycleIncrease;
        if (cyclePosition > 1)
            cyclePosition -= 1; 
        return value;
    }
```

With sawtooth waves I have the same problem:

```
    else if (type == TYPE_SAW)
    {
        cycleIncrease = frequency / parent.getSamplingRate();
        double doubleValue = cyclePosition - Math.floor(cyclePosition);
        cyclePosition += cycleIncrease;
        value = (short) (amplitude * doubleValue);
        if (cyclePosition > 1)
            cyclePosition -= 1; 
        return value;
    }
```

`amplitude` has the value I mentioned above, so in these two cases `100` and `Short.MAX_VALUE`.

The samples are summed up in this way, where `sum` is the output sample and `value` is the calculated sample (0 if no tone is played):

```
    int n = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    for (Wire inputWire:inputWires)
    {
        short value = inputWire.getNextSample();
        if (value != 0)
        {
            n += 1;
        }
        sum += value;
        x++;
    }

    if (n != 0)
        sum = sum / n;
```

I also made sure that there is just the one sample from one oscillator if just one tone is played, so `sum = value`.

But I don't understand why different tones are created for different amplitudes with the same code, so why is this happening?

I also have a second question: If I end playing a sine tone with low amplitude, I can hear a short noise, which looks like this:

[image: noise]

Where does this come from and how can I fix it?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Question 1:

It looks as though you may be wrapping the waveform:

```
if (cyclePosition > 1)
    cyclePosition -= 1; // You are reducing the amplitude by half? (goes from 1 to -1)
```

This is where some clipping should occur:

```
// For example...
if (cyclePosition > 1)
    cyclePosition = 1
if (cyclePosition < -1)
    cyclePosition = -1
```

The Audio may sound bad, but this is what normally happens when the Amplitude is too large.

Maybe try scaling the amplitude to always fit it within bounds:

```
scale = 1 / highestAmplitude;
foreach (point in wavePoints)
{
    point *= scale;
}
// or something similar
```

Question 2:

Make sure the sine wave ends at 0 Amplitude

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the `sampleSizeInBits` of your [`AudioFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioFormat.html) comports with your chosen `amplitude`. If not, you may be seeing a "wrap-around" effect when multiplying by `amplitude`. For reference, this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2065693/230513) scales the sample size to eight bits representing a signed byte value in the range `-128..127`.

```
AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(Note.SAMPLE_RATE, 8, 1, true, true);
…
sin[i] = (byte)(Math.sin(angle) * 127f);
```